# create_connection() method in Python asyncio module

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

The document mentions that `AbstractEventLoop.create_connection`, on successful execution, will return a `(transport, protocol)` tuple. However [all the examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html) show that it returns coroutine.

The [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py) also shows that it does return `(transport, protocol)` tuple. Could you help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both observations are true: [`create_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_connection) is a coroutine function that returns a transport, protocol pair. But to get a hold of that return value, you need to `await` the coroutine (if in an `async def`) or use `loop.run_until_complete` (if in synchronous code).

If you just **call** a coroutine function without awaiting the result, what you get is a coroutine object that you can pass around and await later. This is analogous to how just calling a generator function just returns a generator-iterator; to actually get values out of it, you must exhaust it with a `for` loop.

Many examples don't really need the return value, so they only store the returned coroutine object in a local variable `coro` and then run `run_until_complete(coro)`, effectively discarding the returned transport/protocol pair. The full usage is shown for example in [19.5.4.3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#register-an-open-socket-to-wait-for-data-using-a-protocol):

```
connect_coro = loop.create_connection(MyProtocol, sock=rsock)
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(connect_coro)
```

I believe much of the confusion would disappear if that and other examples were formulated along the lines of:

```
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(
    loop.create_connection(MyProtocol, sock=rsock))
```

That makes it clearer that `create_connection` returns a pair, and that you need `run_until_complete` (the sync equivalent of `await`) to access it, the latter being the case with every coroutine or asyncio future.

Comment: Thanks. I hope the revamped python 3.8 documentation would explain this explicitly too.

Comment: @yoonghm The new docs are announced to present a curio-style approach, where you don't use multiple `run_until_complete` calls, but a single `asyncio.run()` of an `async def` entry point. Such function would contain `t, p = await create_connection(...)` without an explicit reference to the intermediate `coro`. That formulation presents an idiomatic use of asyncio and removes the confusion about the return value of `create_connection` (which is no different than any other asyncio coroutine).